# Why Levenstein distance is calculated without the last insertion

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I have been learning a Levenshtein distance today, and have stummbled upon what it seems to be a strange way of calculation in a well-known Wagner-Fisher algorithm. Please help me find where I've got it wrong.

First string is `Max`.

Second is `Annas`.

A matrix of transformation would be the following:

[image: Levenshtein]

An algorithm reports that the Levenshtein distance from Max to Annas is 4.

So here is how I understand it should work: (given that the cost of any action is 1)

`M` vs `A` -> Replace `m` with `a` (**1** action so far)

`A` vs `N` -> Replace `a` with `n` (**2** actions so far)

`X` vs `N` -> Replace `x` with `n` (**3** actions so far)

After this, we just need to be adding the letters that are left a and s, which take **2** more action from us, resulting in **5** total, not 4.

I see that it is going along a simpler path probably, but what is it? Please explain it's algorithms logic of operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You reconstructed the wrong path. It actually replaces 'm' with 'a', inserts 'n', inserts 'n', *matches* 'a' with 'a', and *inserts 's'^H^H^H^H* replaces 'x' with 's'. Cost 4.

edit: I'm a little too glib to put it like that. There are several cost-4 paths, but they all involve going from ("m","ann") to ("ma","anna").

edit again: I think the key insight is that *not* all actions cost the same; matches are free. That's why the cost grid looks like it does: ("ma","anna") costs 3 because you can get there from ("m", "ann"), which costs 3, by spending **0**. ("max","annas") costs 4 since you can get there from ("ma","anna"), which costs 3, by spending 1.

Comment: maybe replace 'x' with 's' at the end?

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. Noted in the answer.